# Является ли строка временем, проверка с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Имеется паттерн `/d/d:/d/d:/d/d` для времени. Методы `Regex.ISMatching`, `Match` и `Matches` найдут соответствия и в `12:34:56`, и в `a12:34:56`, и в `12:34:56qw`.
Как определить, что некая строка полностью является данным паттерном, без дополнительных проверок.
Например:

```
if (!Regex.IsMatching(text, pattern) || text.Length != 8) return
```

Здесь я делаю дополнительную проверку `text.Length != 8`, а я просто хочу проверить на соответствие паттерну.

Comment: `^/d/d:/d/d:/d/d$` ?

Comment: сейчас проверю...

Comment: Только слеши у вас перекосились :)

Comment: @Андрей, очень странные эти ваши заливные слеши :)

Comment: Спасибо, Андрей (+да я со слешами затупил)

Comment: Использовать именно регулярки — это принцип, или вы просто не знаете альтернатив? Почему не `DateTime.ParseExact`?

Comment: @VladD, а `ParseExact` как валидность проверяет? И будет ли это быстрее?

Comment: @VladD, это к примеру я использовал время, а если бы мне захотелось использовать что-нибудь другое. Я для этого спрашивал

Comment: @Андрей: Это правильнее. Быстрее или нет — вопрос, который необходимо задавать только если есть результат работы профайлера, показывающий, что это реальное узкое место, и что кровь из носу необходимо пожертвовать правильностью ради читабельности.

Comment: @Eugene: Разные типы данных разбираются по-разному. Вы не можете «одинаковым» кодом обрабатывать и `DateTime`, и JSON. Универсальность — ложная цель.

Comment: @VladD, мне главное было узнать об использовании метасимволов "^" и "$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используй **^([0-1]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){2}$** - это корректная маска времени

Comment: ...если подразумевается использование русской локали.